# \newcommands in the \standalone file not recognized in the main file

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, standalone

Few `\newcommands` defined in my standalone `.tex` file containing tikz figure is not recognized in the main `beamer` `.tex` file. Please point out what extra lines should I write to make it work.

Here is the standalone file:

```
% H-atom energy diagram: 1-photon excited 1-photon ionization

\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, decorations.pathmorphing, patterns}

% New commands
\newcommand{\ket}[1]{$\left|#1\right\rangle$}
\newcommand{\Om}[1]{\small $\omega_{#1}$}
\newcommand{\De}[1]{$\Delta_{#1}$}
\newcommand{\ta}[1]{$\tau_{#1}$}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        scale=0.5,
        level/.style={thick},
        virtual/.style={thick,densely dashed},
        trans/.style={thick,<->,shorten >=0pt,shorten <=0pt,>=stealth},
        ionize/.style={thick,->,shorten >=0pt,shorten <=0pt,>=stealth},
        decay/.style={thin,->,decorate,decoration=snake,shorten >=0pt,shorten <=0pt,>=stealth}
        ]
        % Draw the energy levels
        \draw[level] (1cm,4em) node[left]{\scriptsize{13.6eV}} -- (6cm,4em) node[right]{\ket{c}};
        \draw[level] (1cm,0em) node[left]{\scriptsize{10.2eV}} -- (6cm,0em) node[right]{\ket{2p}};
        \draw[level] (1cm,-10em) node[left]{\scriptsize{0eV}} -- (6cm,-10em) node[right]{\ket{1s}};

        % Draw the transitions
        \draw[trans] (3cm,-10em) -- (3cm,0em) node[midway,left] {\scriptsize{122nm}};
        \draw[ionize] (3cm,0em) -- (3cm,10em) node[left] {\scriptsize{122nm}};
        \draw[ionize] (5cm,0em) -- (5cm,8em) node[right] {\scriptsize{355nm}};
        \draw[decay] (3cm,0em) -- (5cm,-3em) node[below] {\scriptsize{\ta{sp}=1.6ns}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is the excerpt from the main file:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
%\tikzexternalize[prefix=i/]
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\epstopdfsetup{outdir=./}

\begin{document}
\title{Main title}
\institute{KU-IAE}
\date{\today}

\frame{\titlepage}

\frame{\frametitle{Table of Contents}\tableofcontents}

\section{This section}
\frame{\frametitle{This section}

    \begin{wrapfigure}{R}{0.4\textwidth}
        \begin{center}
        \includestandalone[width=0.4\textwidth]{figs/2_level_1ph_excite_1ph_ion}
%       \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{figs/H_energy_diagram_1_ph}
        \end{center}
        \caption{this caption}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    Text text text text,
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Text text text text
        \item Text text text text
        \item Text text text text
    \end{itemize}
}
\end{document}
```

The error message excerpt:

> ! Undefined control sequence. l.23 ...ize{13.6eV}} -- (6cm,4em)
>   node[right]{\ket
>                                                     {c}}; ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Pardon me if the format of my post was illegible. I have edited it into compilable form.

Comment: No problem at all, we do not punish here `;-)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\includestandalone` command crops all preamble and starts processing `standalone` file after `\begin{document}`. So, if you include all `\newcommand` after `\begin{document}`, all of them will be available into main file.

You also need to include all packages and libraries used in your standalone file on main file preamble.

Comment: Thank you, Ignasi. I now understand the matter. It solved my problem.